# TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined in component file

Tags: angular

I am working on the task to fetch data using REST API in angular 8.0.0, while doing so i am getting errors as below:

[image]

My task was to display data into the Mat Table on page.

**item.ts**

```
import { Execution } from './execution';
export class Items {
    items: Exec[];
}
```

**execution.ts**

```
export class Exec {
    test: number;
    test1: string;
}
```

**execution.component.ts**

```
export class ExecutionComponent implements OnInit {
  runData: Items;
  constructor(private executionService: ExecutionService) { }  
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['test', 'test1'];  
  //@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Execution>(this.runData.items); //error showing at this point
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.executionService.getArtifactDetails().subscribe(
      (response:Items) => {
        this.runData = response;
        console.log(this.runData);
      }
    );  
  }
}
```

**Sample JSON**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "test": 1,
            "test1": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "test": 2,
            "test1": "EFG",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.runData` is assigned value asynchronously. So it must be used after the value is assigned, inside the subscription. Try the following

```js
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Execution>;

ngOnInit() { 
  this.executionService.getArtifactDetails().subscribe(
    (response: Items) => {
      this.runData = response;
      console.log(this.runData);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Execution>(this.runData.items);
    }
  );  
}
```

More info no how to access asynchronous data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921

Comment: It worked like anything.. thanks a lot. Going to see the above link.